# Looking for an Excel formula that checks a column for a particular value and does a lookup to check 2 different tabs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Picture of First table Where Points column is empty]

[image: Other two identicle columns]

I have a workbook that has 3 tabs... First tab is the table where the points column is empty, I am trying to find a formula that looks at the "Foundation" type and checks either the "Slab" worksheet or the "Crawl" worksheet and then find the amount of points based off the age of the house as well as the amount of windows each house has. The number of points should be at the intersection of the two values "House age" and "Window Count"

I tried a nested If statement with a lookup but as the tables do not have the "House 1" values I cannot use that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted then try something along the lines of using dynamic spill array formulas, formulas shown exclusively works with **`MS365`** :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Slab:Crawl!A2:E13),5),
     b, TAKE(a,12),
     c, DROP(a,12),
     MAP(D2:D6,C2:C6,B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,y,z,LET(w,IF(x="Slab",b,c),
     XLOOKUP(y,DROP(w,1,-4),XLOOKUP(z,TEXTBEFORE(TAKE(w,1,-4)," ")/1,DROP(w,1,1),,-1),,-1)))))
```

---

[image]

---

Download the Excel from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckAQvuHlLx49yle7e?e=gxZIK1)**

Comment: You can make it short : `=LET(b, Slab!A2:E13,c, Crawl!A2:E13, MAP(D2:D6,C2:C6,B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,y,z,LET(w,IF(x="Slab",b,c),XLOOKUP(y,DROP(w,1,-4),XLOOKUP(z,TEXTBEFORE(TAKE(w,1,-4)," ")/1,DROP(w,1,1),,-1),,-1)))))`